# All backslashes are being removed from local file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

*(I'm an Actionscript/Flex developer and am making the transition to Javascript. This is probably a silly question and a duplicate but I no idea if the issue is related to Javascript, Electron, web development in general, etc. Please be kind.)*

I've been developing a simple project using Electron and the `Fabric.js` using OSX. The functionality is that the user can select a local image file and annotate it. Works fine and I am learning a lot. However I brought it over to Windows and it breaks due to the path of the user-selected image file being munged.

All the backslashes are being removed from the path for some reason. Can someone explain what is going on and how I resolve this?

> **OSX**
>   **path** /Users/Rocket/Desktop/house.jpg
>   **cmd:** loadImage("/Users/Rocket/Desktop/house.jpg")
>   **loadImage:** /Users/Rocket/Desktop/house.jpg
>
> **Windows**
>   **path:** C:\Users\Windows7\Desktop\assets\house.jpg
>   **cmd:** loadImage("C:\Users\Windows7\Desktop\assets\house.jpg")
>   **loadImage:** C:UsersWindows7Desktopassetshouse.jpg

If I log the `filenames`parameter of the `filePickerCallback` callback I see all double backslashes. When I use the first item of that array in a variable all the double backslashes are converted to single backslashes. Baffling.

```
[ 'C:\\Users\\Windows7\\Desktop\\assets\\house.jpg' ]
```

---

In Electron (Node?) Context:

```
function showFilePicker() {
    var options = {
        title: "Select Image",
        properties: ['openFile'],
        filters: [
            { name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png'] },
        ],
    }
    dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, options, filePickerCallback);
}

function filePickerCallback(filenames) {
    if (filenames && filenames.length > 0) {
        var path = filenames[0];
        console.log('path',path);

        var cmd = 'loadImage(' + '\"' + path + '\"' + ')'
        console.log('cmd', cmd);

        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(cmd);
    }
}
```

---

In Render Context

```
function loadImage(filepath) {
    console.log('loadImage', filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript backslash is interpreted as an escape for the next character.

```
`console.log('\a\b\c');` 
             //==>  ac   ( escaped a is a, escaped b is backspace ,  escaped c is c'
```

If you want backslashes in your string you have to escape those too

```
`console.log('\\a\\b\\c');` 
            //==> \a\b\c
```

In other words the first backslash in \ gets eaten as an escape indicator :)